# Questions with updating objects in java

Tags: java, oop, reference

If I have an instance of an object, and within that object is a variable that holds the data of another object. If I ever update the second object will the copy of that object be updated as well or do I need to simultaneously update all copies of said object.

For example:

```
public class Object()
{
    int x = xValue;
    Object linked = saidObject;
}

public class doStuff()
{
   saidObject.x++;
   if(linked.equals(saidObject))
       return true;
}
```

will this code (not compilable obviously just fill in blanks) return true?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a "class", an instance of a class (generally referred to as an "object" or "object instance") and a "reference".  All instances of a class have the same "shape" but contain entirely separate data values.  But a single instance of a class can be addressed by multiple references.  Changing a field in a given class instance will not change other instances of the same class, but if multiple references address a single object, a change through any one reference to the object will be visible through all references to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(linked.equals(saidObject))` will return true as the two variables do point to the same object.

In Java all variables and fields are references to an actual Object that lives somewhere in memory.

When you assign one variable to another, it's like copying the address of the object so that they both point to the same object in memory.

e.g.

```
Object a = new Object();  // this actually creates the Object in memory
Object b = a;             // this copies the reference to Object from a to b
// At this point, a and b point to exactly the same object in memory. Therefore ...
a.equals(b);              // returns true.
```

In fact `a == b` returns true too, which is a better way of comparing for this case as `==` compares if two variables point to the same object (they do), whereas `equals()` often compares by value, which is unnecessary here.

It doesn't matter if `b` is actually a field within `a` (e.g. `class Obj { Obj b; };  Obj a = new Obj(); a.b = a;`) and it points to the same type of object, the principle is the same: `a = b` means they point to same object, nothing new is created.

Comment: very useful. I just wasn't certain of how assigning variables works with java. thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. I answered in the spirit of the question but note your code isn't really compilable Java. In particular you don't actually create an instance of the Object anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

By doing:

```
Object linked = saidObject;
```

you are not copying the object, just creating another pointer to it, it means you have two different pointers that point to the same object.

copying or cloning an object can be useful in some cases but its not the usual case.

Answer (score 0):

An object instance is itself and is distinct from every other instance.

That is, mutating an object (by reassigning a field) *someplace* modifies it *everywhere* .. as, well, it is what it is. Likewise, mutating a *different* object .. is, well, changing a *different* object.

Comment: So if I create object 1 and assign it values of object 2, then change object 2, object 1 will also be changed?

Comment: @SpiderShlong No. It's exactly the opposite. Each time you `new`, a *different* object is created.

Comment: ok thought so =\ that makes my code much for difficult. thanks

Comment: @SpiderShlong It doesn't necessarily have to be more difficult. If you create a question showing the *actual* code and the *actual* problem attempted, there might be easier solutions. This "answer" is rather vague because there wasn't an *actual* problem to go with.

Comment: I've made like 3 threads asking for help with my dijkstra's algorithm and realized this was the key flaw I had that caused me to rewrite the entire thing 4 times. Currently I'm looking at [link](http://en.literateprograms.org/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29#chunk def:simple compute paths function) which seems to use this way of assigning vertex edges.